# Font Awesome Swift: "Ambiguous Use of Code"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, font-awesome

I'm trying to implement FontAwesome icons in my app using this https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift package. I followed all the instructions correctly but for some reason, when I'm trying to implement an icon into my navbar like so:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20)] as [String: Any]
mapButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
mapButton.title = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .globe)
```

I get the error: `Ambiguous use of 'fontAwesome(name:)'` and xcode says it found these two candidates:

```
 /// Get a FontAwesome icon string with the given icon name.
 ///
 /// - parameter name: The preferred icon name.
 /// - returns: A string that will appear as icon with FontAwesome.
 public static func fontAwesomeIcon(name: FontAwesome) -> String {
     return name.rawValue.substring(to: name.rawValue.characters.index(name.rawValue.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
 }
/// Get a FontAwesome icon string with the given CSS icon code. Icon code can be found here: http://fontawesome.io/icons/
///
/// - parameter code: The preferred icon name.
/// - returns: A string that will appear as icon with FontAwesome.
public static func fontAwesomeIcon(code: String) -> String? {

    guard let name = self.fontAwesome(code: code) else {
        return nil
    }

  return self.fontAwesomeIcon(name: name)
}
```

The demo files in this package work fine so I'm confused as to why my code won't work. Is there any way to choose a candidate for xcode to run by default?

Comment: Can't reproduce (as I explain in my answer below). Your code, as shown, should compile. I would have to suggest that either you have not described the problem correctly (maybe the error is from a line you didn't actually show us?) or you didn't incorporate FontAwesome into your project correctly. As a last resort, try quitting Xcode and cleaning out the DerivedData folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I'm trying to implement an icon into my navbar

So exactly what is `mapButton`? Is it a UIBarButtonItem? Because if it is, your code should compile just fine. I tried this:

```
let mapButton = UIBarItem() // my code
// the rest is _exactly_ your code!
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20)] as [String: Any]
mapButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
mapButton.title = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .globe)
```

It compiles just fine.

> Ambiguous use of `fontAwesome(name:)`

Really? If you were to write `fontAwesome(name:)`, you would certainly get a compile error, because the term `fontAwesome` is not the same as the term `fontAwesomeIcon`. But in that case your code and your error message don't go together! And in any case, the error message I get, if I deliberately make that mistake, is a different error.

Comment: My bar button was an outlet before but even trying it the way you wrote it gave me the same error. You're right, I typed the error wrong it's actually 'fontAwesomeItem(name:)' and not 'fontAwesome(name:)'

Comment: If you post the project somewhere (dropbox, github, whatever) in its current state, I'll be happy to take a look at it for you. This should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it -- I reinstalled the pod and it worked. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Well, I think my answer was right. Your error was not reproducible and your code was correct, just as I said. And in my comment I did suggest you'd configured things incorrectly, which seems to be the case.